# Define Regular Expression Validation for custom DataType in MVC4

Tags: regex, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I upgraded a project from MVC3 to MVC4 and noticed that one of my validators wasn't triggering anymore.  I chased it down to a custom DataType in the Shared/EditorTemplates folder that is used for capturing Social Security numbers in various forms across the site.  (We only show the last 4 digits when the page is loaded after a save, to explain the regex.)

**SSN.cshtml**

```
@{
    var ssn = (string)ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue;
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ssn)){
        ssn = "###-##-" + Model.Substring(Model.Length - 4, 4);
    }
}
@Html.TextBox("", ssn, new { @class = "text-box single-line ssn", pattern = @"^(\d{3}|###)-(\d{2}|##)-\d{4}$", placeholder = "###-##-####", title = "Expected pattern is ###-##-####" })
```

It seems like in MVC4 the unobtrusive validation wants to look for **data-val-regex-pattern** as an attribute of the rendered text box, not just **pattern**.  Has anyone ran into this before?

*Note:  I'd like to keep the validation on the custom data type so I don't have to always remember to add it to each model.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that in order to get MVC4 to render the correct data attributes to the input field, I'd need to replace the hyphens with underscores in the anonymous object passed to the TextBox helper.  Here's the code that I ended up with:
**SSN.cshtml**

```
@{
    var ssn = (string)ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue;
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ssn) && ssn.Length == 11)
    {
        ssn = "###-##-" + Model.Substring(Model.Length - 4, 4);
    }
    else {
        ssn = "";
    }
}
@Html.TextBox("", ssn,
    new
    {
        @class = "text-box single-line ssn",
        data_val = "true",
        data_val_regex_pattern = @"^(\d{3}|###)-(\d{2}|##)-\d{4}$",
        data_val_regex = "Expected pattern is ###-##-####",
        placeholder = "###-##-####"
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have your own custom validator and put it in the model property. here is an example

```
public class SocialSecurityAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public SocialSecurityAttribute () : base(@"^(\d{3}|###)-(\d{2}|##)-\d{4}$") { }
}
```

Then register it in the global asax.cs Application start as follows

```
  DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(SocialSecurityAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
```

When you use it , it will be like any other built in attributes

```
[SocialSecurity(ErrorMessage ...)]
public string SocialSecurityNumber{get;set;}
```

I like implementing like this as the code can be reused . Otherwise you can just use RegularExpressionAttribute passsing the regex

Comment: Does the client side unobtrusive validation still work when you do this?

Comment: While that would work, I'd still have to add that to all of the models that use this data type.  I'm hoping to have that data attribute added to the input when it's rendered.