# Can I use Data Annotations Validation on my POCOs and jQuery validation if I develop the front end in Angular 1 instead of Razor?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, poco

Normally when developing in ASP.Net MVC, we put our Data Annotions on our POCOs and use isModel.Valid on the server side and unobtrusive jQuery validation on the front end so we don't have to duplicate and specify our validation requirements twice.

But I am about to try writing my first app with an Angular/Rest SPA architecture (ASP.Net Web API of course, more specifically, ASP.Net MVC Core).

Is there a way to get the Angular Forms to validate against the POCO validation attribute rules and keep it DRY?  Or am I going to have to maintain it in both places?  Client and Server.

What is the best practice here?
Can someone point me to an example if there is a correct way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define Regular Expression Validation for custom DataType in MVC4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323591/define-regular-expression-validation-for-custom-datatype-in-mvc4)